# How to map this character array to integers?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a character Array which i have to map these characters into integers. It works like this. - The final character in the array has to be 0, followed by the next distinct character = 1 and so on.

I already have the characters in the array i just cant seem to Map them correctly

This is what i have tried

```
public void generate(String first, String second) {
    letters = new char[(first+second).length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i ++) { //Getting the string as characters into array
        letters = (first+second).toCharArray();
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
        for(int m = letters.length; m > 0; m--) {
            letters[m] = (char) j;
        }
    }

}
```

which gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at PuzzleGenerator.generate(PuzzleGenerator.java:21)
at test.main(test.java:7)
```

Comment: What is the use of first loop ?Your requirement is not clear . Please elaborate

Comment: @Rehman -- My first loop turns both of the strings into characters inside the array.

Answer (score 1):

You answer is unclear, but maybe this is what you want:

```
  public static int[] generate(String first, String second) {
    return (first + second)
      .chars()
      .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, i)
                      .boxed()
                      .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
                      .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf))
      .toArray();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int m = letters.length; m > 0; m--) {
        letters[m] = (char) j;
    }
```

This loop starts at letters.length this gives you the exception.
You should write it like this:

```
    for(int m = letters.length; m-- > 0; ) {
        letters[m] = (char) j;
    }
```

I do not really understand what you are trying to do but the first loop should be replaced with just

```
letters = (first+second).toCharArray();
```

Doing it once is enough.

Comment: ```for(int m = letters.length; m-- > 0; ) {
        letters[m] = (char) j;
    }``` Please, please, please, never do it! It is unclear at all! Condition with side-effect is pure evil!